# dynaming linking error with pbs-drmaa

Tags: gcc, dynamic-linking, drmaa

I've installed pbs-drmaa library, but I get an error while running a C program.

Here's the compilation, I've used -L and -I to indicate the proper folders for pbs-drmaa files. As it shows, there's no compilation error:

```
$ gcc teste_drmaa1.c -L /usr/lib/pbs-drmaa/lib -I /usr/lib/pbs-drmaa/include -ldrmaa -o teste_drmaa1
```

But when I try to run, I get an error:

```
$./teste_drmaa1 

./teste_drmaa1: error while loading shared libraries: libdrmaa.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But the file exists in the path given for -L:

```
ls /usr/lib/pbs-drmaa/lib
libdrmaa.so@  libdrmaa.so.1@  libdrmaa.so.1.0.10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure that **/usr/lib/pbs-drmaa/lib** is in the path

Comment: What do you mean by 'is in the path'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved running ldconfig.

Now compilation is:

```
gcc teste_drmaa1.c -ldrmaa -o teste_drmaa1
```